# Google Sheets conditional formatting value where 1 column value lower than other column

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

My data:

```
E       F
25.00%  11.11%
30      20
10      20
40      40
0       10
20      0
```

I want to have conditional formatting where:
- if value in column F is lower than E, cell F should be colored red
- if value in column F is equal or higher than E, cell F should be colored green
- if value in column E is 0, don't apply any color on cell F

I tried with 2 rules simply using the dropdown values
"Greater than or equal to" and "Less than". I tried that on a single cell, see image, but that doesn't work either and the higher value is marked as red.
I tried a custom formula on the whole sheet `=F31<=E31` and `=F31>E31` but neither give the desired result.

This should be so simple but I'm missing something.

I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31293966/google-sheets-conditional-formatting-based-on-two-cells) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17356466/color-cell-red-if-cell-above-value-is-lower?noredirect=1&lq=1).
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Custom Formulas  -  Conditional Formating

```
#   GREEN Format
#   - E30 not zero, and
#   - F30 greater than or equal to E30

    =AND(E30<>0,F30>=E30)


#   RED Format
#   - E30 not zero, and
#   - F30 less than E30

    =AND(E30<>0,F30<E30)
```

[image]
[image]   [image]